# Sending files between computers [Cloud Server <-> Home Computer]

Tags: ssh, scp

I'm using a cloud server which runs ubuntu, I can send files from my computer to the server using scp, but the opposite side doesnt work, I know it could be due to closed ports or something else.
anyhow, what options do I have? I need one file, generated on the server to be on my home computer.

I'm using SSH for the connections to the server's shell.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are starting scp on your local host [2] and not on the remote host [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS), are you? Only with [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) you could run into blocked ports on your home computer.

```
1: remoteuser@remotecomputer:~$ scp /path/to/file/foobar.txt homeuser@homecomputer:
2: homeuser@homecomputer:~$ scp remoteuser@remotehost:/path/to/file/foobar.txt .
```

For your convenience you can try [SSHFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use SFTP, which comes with Ubuntu's ssh package and works in either direction.  You can't scp from the remote host to your local PC unless you're running sshd (the ssh server) locally.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect with a grafical interface as WinSCP ( http://winscp.net ), that runs over SSH. You have to install it on your local machine, and SSH server on your server (i guess you have already done).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [rsync over ssh](http://oreilly.com/pub/h/38)?

> While tar over ssh is ideal for making remote copies of parts of a filesystem, rsync is even better suited for keeping the filesystem in sync between two machines. Typically, tar is used for the initial copy, and rsync is used to pick up whatever has changed since the last copy. This is because tar tends to be faster than rsync when none of the destination files exist, but rsync is much faster than tar when there are only a few differences between the two filesystems.